# How can I get the Vendor's Name and Product Name from a USB Device VID and PID on Windows?

Tags: windows, delphi, usb

I know I can look it up [here](http://www.linux-usb.org/usb.ids) but I don't want to invent a half baked solution that requires maintenance. How does Windows get that information?  I've read that you can get it from the Windows Registry, but with my scanner Windows displays the correct information, but I cannot locate any info in the registry.  If it's recorded in the registry how can I get it programmatically?

Comment: Are you looking for `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\USB` in the Windows Registry?

Comment: I looked into the Registry entries but did not find the friendly name that was listed in the device manager.  It's important to use and display the same information as Windows.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/setupapi/nf-setupapi-setupdigetdeviceregistrypropertya)  api will do the job